# array data store to localStorage is not working in internet explorer, but work properly in chrome

Tags: javascript

Here is the javascript code.

```
var arr = [];
var dynamicValue;
var i = 0;
if(dynamicValue=="A")
{
   arr[i++] = dynamicValue;
   localStorage["Data"] =JSON.stringify(arr);
}
```

Please kindly help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Compatibility

Comment: Hi kavun, I used IE9,IE10. Both are not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is happening that is different from your expectation?

Comment: "not working" means I can not store my data to localStorage. When I reached to this line 'localStorage["Data"] =JSON.stringify(arr);', it stop and not go through to next code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
    var arr = [];
    var dynamicValue;
    var i = 0;
    if(dynamicValue=="A")
    {
       arr[i++] = dynamicValue;
       localStorage("Data") =JSON.stringify(arr);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Amnesh Goel , I have tried your code. Still same error.

Comment: Could you alert(JSON.stringify(arr)); ? and could you place one alert after arr[i++] = dynamicValue; as alert(arr[i]); and let me know what happens.

Comment: I can get alert1 after arr[i++]. Also I put one alert2 after localStorage("Data") =JSON.stringify(arr);.  But this alert2 did not prompt.

Comment: Did you get the value from alert(JSON.stringify(arr)); before faulty statement? If yes then try with more alert as alert(localstorage('Data')); alert(localstorage("data")); alert(localstorage['Data']); alert(localstorage["data"]); and check where your code is breaking...

Comment: Yes, I got the value from alert(JSON.stringify(arr)); before faulty statement. Only I am not able to store this value to localStorage.

Comment: Is localstorage a hidden variable? or what is the need of localstroage in your context. If you are storing this value to use at the server side then you can do it via Hidden variables or ViewState variables.